# Is it possible set a hint for android buttons?

Tags: android

Is it possible set a hint for the button in android?

Comment: If you mean the hint like you hover your mouse on top of a hyperlink in (desktop) browsers, I don't think so. You don't have any 'hovering' of fingers on top of any control in current Android devices, right?

Comment: @xandy. Whether the hint actually shows I don't know but it can be set.

Comment: @sugarynugs, you are right. I really doubt how can it be shown. Anyway, the 'hint' property is actually inherited from 'TextView' (well, Button is the child of TextView), and I don't see any purpose of that in Button; It is meaningful, to, editable text, but not to any readonly text (including TextView in most cases).

Comment: @xandy.  I mentioned the inheritance in my answer and having now tested it the hint only shows when text is not set.  So I marked up Alain's answer.  I can only think he did mean a `tooltip` like you guys reckoned.

Answer (score 5):

The hint property is only taken into account as a default substitute if the Button text is absent.  It is not a real "tooltip" as in HTML title attribute you can see when you hover over an element.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `myButton.setHint` in code or `android:hint` in XML.  A `Button` inherits them from `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also drg and drop onto your GUI and right click on the button, and select hint.